# HP ML350 G5 Smart Array E200i battery error

Tags: storage, hp-proliant, windows-sbs-2003, hp-smart-array

We have replaced the server with a new battery pack but still getting the error.

[image]

Can you tell what is wrong with it, as it is urgent before the server generates more errors.

Answer (score 6):

Your battery failed. Given the age of your server, that's normal. However, you state that you replaced the bad battery... You may be running into one of the early RAID controller bugs that incorrectly reports failed BBWC units. But the problem is most-likely that the battery is charging. This process takes a few hours... How long did you wait following replacement?

One thing you'll need to do is [update the firmware](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3279711&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121586%257CswItem%253DMTX-df27c58c24114616bb400d6cdf%257CprodNameId%253D3279711%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CswLang%253D8%257Cmode%253D3%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) of your Smart Array E200i RAID controller. Your screenshot indicates that the version of your E200i firmware dates back to 2007. If you look at the [extensive list of changes/bugfixes/revisions since that time](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3279711&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121586%257CswItem%253DMTX-df27c58c24114616bb400d6cdf%257CprodNameId%253D3279711%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CswLang%253D8%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), you'll see that there's a benefit to keeping the firmware up-to-date.

For your OS, Windows SBS 2003, all you'll need to do is [obtain the firmware download here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3279711&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121586%257CswItem%253DMTX-df27c58c24114616bb400d6cdf%257CprodNameId%253D3279711%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CswLang%253D8%257Cmode%253D3%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), run the installer and reboot.

While you're there, updating the [server's firmware](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3279711&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D1121586%257CprodNameId%253D3279711%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-bb57d530aeb447f8a7f994b4dd%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) may also be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the BBWC itself (small card with SPN (Spare Part Number) 351518-001 fitted on the motherbrd) has problems.
Whenever after replacing the battery the status after 1 or 2 days is again faulty, then you've got to replace:
1) Battery (SPN 307132-001) (again)
2) BBWC (replace it with SPN **413486-001**: this BBWC 128MB doesn't have this problem