# HP ML350 G5 Smart Array E200i battery voltage not low

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, windows-sbs-2003, hp-smart-array

I have a similar problem like this: [HP ML350 G5 Smart Array E200i battery error](https://serverfault.com/questions/406244/hp-ml350-g5-smart-array-e200i-battery-error)

Gets error message that says it is low voltage power on battery. Has measured voltages of the battery and it is exactly what it should be.
Error code is: 269

Anybody have an idea what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

Do exactly what was specified in the [**answer to the question you linked**](https://serverfault.com/a/406249/13325).

The RAID controller battery is a user-servicable part. It has a planned lifetime of ~3 years.

*You* should replace the battery (Call HP). Also upgrade your controller firmware, since old versions of the firmware falsely reported bad battery status.

Comment: The firmware is up to date. But i check the voltage of battery, and it's perfect...

Comment: Which server model and controller are you using? Is your server under warranty?

Comment: Its a HP ML350 G5 with Smart Array E200i SCSI controller.
Using a multimeter to be sure it was okay with battery power.I reset the bios, it solved the problem.